# Как сделать так, чтоб на разных аккаунтов были разные посты на nestJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nestjs

как сделать, чтоб у каждого юзера была своя информация. Например: пользователь на аккаунте test1 создал определенные посты,эти посты сохраняются на аккаунте, потом пользователь выходит из этого аккаунта и заходит в аккаунт test2 и на этом аккаунте этих постов уже нет, как хранить массивы добавленных данных для каждого аккаунта? Как сделать это на nestJs?

Comment: nest вам тут особо не поможет. Вам база данных нужна, куда бы все эти посты сохранялись и выбирались по логину пользователя

Comment: без бэкенда - никак

Comment: Так это понятно, я просто не могу понять, какую структуру юзера сделать в бд

Comment: @MaksimOstroginskiy да вроде просто: в теле модели каждого пользователя массив постов